# Floating point arithmetic: $(x-2)^9$

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, floating-point

This is taken from Trefethen and Bau, 13.3.

Why is there a difference in accuracy between evaluating near 2 the expression $(x-2)^9$ and this expression:

$$x^9 - 18x^8 + 144x^7 -672x^6 + 2016x^5 - 4032x^4 + 5376x^3 - 4608x^2 + 2304x - 512 $$

Where exactly is the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Each term has a different order of magnitude therefore there will be losses with addition. With the former you are just multiplying the exponent by nine after subtracting only 2 from the mantissa.

Comment: @Alizter: Thanks, but why when I delete any of the terms, there's no problem with accuracy? I still have terms with different order of magnitude.

Comment: $x^9$ grows very large.

Comment: @Alizter: I get the same effect with (x-1)^9 near 1...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$(x-2)$ is small by definition of $x$, $(x-2)^9$ is even much smaller but can be computed with small relative error.
The single terms of the expanded polynomial are much larger and therefore you will suffer from **catastrophic cancellation** (see e.g. [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance) or do a web search). Example:
$$x=2 + 10^{-2} \Longrightarrow (x-2)^9 = 10^{-18}.$$ This is below the machine epsilon for double! Now with your expanded polynom  you have to compute
$-512 + 23.04 \pm \dots$.

And here is the actual computation with double and evaluation of the polynomial using Horner for $x=2.01:$

```
(x-2)^9 = 9.99999999999808E-019      poly(x) =  -3.75166564481333E-012
```

As expected the polynomial result is completely wrong (in terms of relative error), but
note that even the relative error for the first is about $2\cdot 10^{-13},$ which is a result from the fact that $0.01$ cannot represented exactly as double.

Answer (score 3):

I have tried to plot this 2 expresions near x=2.0. Look at the image. The behaviour ( shape) seems very different .

[image]

Here is the Maxima CAS code :

```
draw2d(
  file_name = "d",
  color = blue,
  key = "second function",
  explicit(x^9 - 18*x^8 + 144*x^7 -672*x^6 + 2016*x^5 - 4032*x^4 + 5376*x^3 - 4608*x^2 + 2304*x - 512 ,x, 2-0.0000005,2.0000005),

  color = red,
  key = " y = (x-2)^9",
  explicit((x-2)^9, x, 2-0.0000005,2.0000005),

  terminal = 'svg) $
```

Note that above 2 expressions are the same !

```
expand((x-2)^9)
```

So problem is in computer arithmethic not in math ( informally speaking)
More : [stable evaluation of polynomials](https://archive.org/details/jresv71Bn1p11)  . See also [discussion](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.mathematics.maxima.general/47209)