# Is loss of significance chaotic?

Tags: fractals, floating-point, chaos-theory

This image on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance), originally taken from [this Math.SE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/995489/floating-point-arithmetic-x-29/1000443#1000443), shows $(x - 2)^9$ in expanded and factored form, plotted with a computer using floating point arithemetic. [image]

The image shows the dramatic loss of significance due to cancellation in the expanded expression, $x^{9} - 18 x^{8} + 144 x^{7} - 672 x^{6} + 2016 x^{5} - 4032 x^{4} + 5376 x^{3} - 4608 x^{2} + 2304 x - 512$.

The thing that interests me, however, is that in this plot, the exact error at any given point appears to be random/fractal in nature. There also appears to be a gap near the right side of the graph, which I am curious about. I made my own version of this plot using numpy and matplotlib, and saw no such gap:

[image]

Here is the same plot zoomed in a few times in a random location, until you can see the individual points, so you can see apparent fractal nature:

[image]

Here is the code for the plot, if anyone is interested

```
from sympy import symbols, lambdify, expand
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = symbols('x')
a = lambdify(x, (x - 2)**9, 'numpy')
a = lambdify(x, expand((x - 2)**9), 'numpy')

xvals = xvals = np.linspace(2-0.0000005,2.0000005, 16000)
plt.plot(xvals, a(xvals), linewidth=0.1)
plt.plot(xvals, b(xvals), linewidth=0.1)
```

So my question is, is there a mathematical explanation for the apparent chaotic/fractal nature of the loss of significance due to cancellation.

**EDIT**

Here is the same plot for $(x - 3)^9$

[image]

and here is the same plot for $(x - 4)^9$

[image]

These seem to confirm H. H. Rugh's idea that the increase in the maximum magnitude after 2 in the first plot is due to passing a power of 2 and needing an extra bit to represent the number, as the first plot has roughly uniform magnitude and the second has a similar increase for values greater than 4.

Answer (score 3):

More like thoughts than rigour: Interesting plots! I believe that the plots correspond to weighted sums of 9 (or 10?) random variables (probably close to independent but not quite). In each term, say $-18 x^8$ you get en error in the result which is like a random variable in the last binary digit. Since $x$ doesn't vary much it's fairly homogeneous. But in the high powers the error varies more rapidly than in low powers so there are probably different scales in the variation (whence the 'fractal' structure).

However, your first plot shows a curious phenomena when you get above 2. The variance seems to be multiplied by roughly 2 (my guess) which may be related to the fact that in binary when above 2 you need one more digit to represent the number $x$ (and its powers) so you loose one digit of precision in the end.

Comment: Interesting. I hadn't considered that that was the reason for the jump in magnitude at 2 (which I also forgot to mention in my question). If that theory is correct, you should see the same thing for $(x - 4)^9$ (but not $(x - 3)^9$).

Comment: Yes, could be of interest to test !

Comment: Another interesting test would be to do the same calculation in lower precision (why not single?) and look at the differences with the double precision for each term. I guess that you will see quite some nice pattern in the errors, like waves (not necessarily continuous, though) with shorter 'wavelength' for the higher powers of $x$

Comment: I tested edited the question with plots for $(x - 3)^9$ and $(x - 4)^9$. Your theory seems to hold. I'm guessing this is why the original creators of this example (Trefethen and Bau, 13.3 according to the [other Math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/995489/floating-point-arithmetic-x-29/1000443#1000443)) chose 2 specifically for $(x - 2)^9$, as it demonstrates this particular issue with loss of significance.

Comment: Nice! If you are also able to see the pattern of precision loss for each term (like comparing with single precision, if possible on your calculator program) that would be great.

Comment: Some adjustments are needed for your other idea. It seems that for single precision, the loss of significance is much higher (on the order of 0.001), vs. double precision where it's on the order of 1e-11 (that is, higher precision leads to more precise results!).

Comment: That's ok. The question is how the variation in the error looks like when you vary $x$ for each of the ten terms. I bet that for the high powers of $x$ the errors will have smaller 'wavelength' (but could be wrong)

Comment: Another 'silly' idea: If you look at $(x^2-2)^5$ then you might also see this jump phenomena at $x=\sqrt{2}$ but with less amplitude as only half the terms will 'encounter' the problem.

Answer (score 1):

One message is that, for a polynomial with integer coefficients, you will get better results by taking the Taylor polynomial around the nearest integer. You can still do that for rational coefficients or very pleasant algebraic ones, after that not much can be done, I imagine.